# checking if file exists in a specific directory

Tags: java, directory, file-exists

I am trying to check for a specific file in a given directory. I don't want the code but I want to fix the one I have. The only difference in this question, is that I look for files with an extension `.MOD`.

I have the code ready:-

```
public static int checkExists(String directory, String file) {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    File[] dir_contents = dir.listFiles();
    String temp = file + ".MOD";
    boolean check = new File(temp).exists();
    System.out.println("Check"+check);  // -->always says false

    for(int i = 0; i<dir_contents.length;i++) {
        if(dir_contents[i].getName() == (file + ".MOD"))
            return Constants.FILE_EXISTS;
    }

    return Constants.FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
}
```

But for some reasons, it does not work. I don't understand why, can anybody find any bug here?

Comment: did you already printed out the tmp value and check if the file really exists? And if so, which env is this (windows or linux) in linux files are case sensitive...

Comment: yes I tried printing the temp value and the file indeed exists in the directory. It is windows OS, but the `file` parameter and the actual name of the file in the directory are case-sensitively same.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do you expect temp.MOD file to be in the current directory (the directory from which you run your application), or you want it to be in the "directory" folder? In the latter case, try creating the file this way:

```
boolean check = new File(directory, temp).exists();
```

Also check for the file permissions, because it will fail on permission errors as well. Case sensitivily might also be the cause of the issue as Spaeth mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

This is where you have the bug.

```
String temp = file + ".MOD";
```

And

```
if(dir_contents[i].getName() == (file + ".MOD"))
```

The code `boolean check = new File(temp).exists();` will check for the file in the current directory not in the required directory.

```
    String dirName="/home/demo";
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    File[] dir_contents = dir.listFiles();
    String temp = dirName+"/"+"README" + ".MOD";
    boolean check = new File(temp).exists();
    System.out.println("Check" + check); // -->always says false

    for (int i = 0; i < dir_contents.length; i++) {
        if (dir_contents[i].getName().equals("README" + ".MOD"))
            return Constants.FILE_EXISTS;
            }

    return Constants.FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
```

Comment: @gkris and you have to use .equals() in the for loop

Comment: for loop is just another method of checking the same file existence. I had 2 methods to check the same function because none were working. Now I can safely remove the whole for loop. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this..............

```
File f = new File("./file_name");
if(f.exists()){
    System.out.println("success");
}
else{
    System.out.println("fail");
}
```

Comment: this wont help because I am not checking for the file in current directory. Anyways I got the answer and accepted it too. Thanks

Comment: Well that what i mean in path...ok new File("./file_name");           "." (dot) operator means the current directory

Comment: Then simply give the path of the file that is needed