# How to Check if a File Exists in a Directory in Java

Tags: java, file-io, directory, file-exists

I would like to find out if a particular directory has a file in it already in Java, specifically I need to check if the file exists in a given directory using Java code.

However, I need the code to not crash and burn due to the various permissions / file rights and how it can be used. It's going in a cross platform app. I've seen the question [checking if file exists in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220678/checking-if-file-exists-in-a-specific-directory) this isn't what I'm needing however.

Any kind soles with some clean Java code ideas.. (sorry if my English is bad I'm not American).

Update: Found what I needed eventually https://javajudo.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory-in-java/

Thanks, for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test whether a file or directory exists using the Java File `exists()` method.

```
File file = new File("/temp.txt");
boolean cond1 = file.exists();
```

The method will return true when the file or directory is found and false if the file is not found.

You can also use the `Files.exists()` and `Files.notExists()` Java methods if that is easier too.

There are also the constants `Constants.FILE_EXISTS` and `Constants.FILE_EXISTS` you can use to test conditions.

Comment: This should work cross platform too I forget to day.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
boolean check_if_file_exists(String file_path)
{
    if (file_path != null)
    {
        File f = new File(file_path);
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```